# Python multiprocessing for each key in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am new to python and i am trying to scale my processing in parallel. I have a file with certain number of tuples, each with certain value in the last column. I want to split this file data and apply my function in parallel to each chunk. But the thing is to split the data in to chunks based on last column value and apply the function for each chunk. For example, last column may have 'a' for some tuples and 'b' for some and 'c' for some. So in that case, i should get three chunks and process it in parallel. Number of unique values in last column may change depends on dataset, so i need to use the CPU accordingly.

Q1:
What i tried till now is to read the file and created a dictionary based on that records, so basically three key-value pairs for the above one, one with 'a' as key and all records having 'a' as values and the same to 'b' and 'c'. I can make use of chunksize in multiprocessing, but here it is not size, its based on key, so how can i achieve this?

Q2: 
After processing the above chunks, i need the output of all together,order does not matter and then i need to use the whole output for further processing, how can i make my main program wait till all those process complete?

Let me know if further input is required. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to split your input into three fixed groups? Isn't the function to apply to all of them the same? If it is, it's much easier to do this if you don't insist on splitting manually - that is, split the data *after* you have the function results

Comment: Yes its same function, but i have to apply this separately for each set of records having the same value on last column. And its not three fixed groups, its the number of unique values in the last column.

Comment: Can't you separate them after the parallel process?

Comment: No, function has to run only for that particular set of record, because its going to do combinations of those records, so it should not mix with the records with different id in last column.

Comment: So the function operates on the set of records, and not on each record individually? If so, what you want is concurrent processing of the three sets?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. it operates on the set of records with same value on last column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming, as you described, you have a three sets as values on dictionary `d`, and want to apply function `f` to each of them separately:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool()                                   #number of processes = number of CPUs
keys, values= zip(*d.iteritems())            #ordered keys and values
processed_values= p.map( f, values )         #apply the function f to each set and wait for result
#then proceed to join the three sets
```

Comment: Do we need to hardcode the number of CPU? Is it possible to program it in such a way that it gets the number of processes based on the number of keys in my dictionary? I will have more number of CPUs and hopefully my number of keys will never exceed the CPU limit. So, i want to take that.

Comment: @Jeeva You can provide the number of processes as the single argument :`Pool(len(d))`, but it may not bring you any considerable advantage, as processes will be left unused if `n_processes<n_tasks` (and, hopefully, the creation of a process is very lightweight when compared to `f`)

Comment: No, thats why i think of taking number of processes in to my program based on the number of keys. If i have four set of records or four keys, i can initialize this p = Pool(4) based on that right? And one more thing i am using python 3.4, i am getting an error - AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: @Jeeva You can, if you're sure `n_cpus>=n_tasks` always holds (otherwise you'll have multiple busy processes on the same cpu, which is not terrible, but usually not ideal either). On python 3, `iteritems` was renamed to `items`

Comment: Ok, i added this at the end, p.close() # no more tasks
    p.join()  # wrap up current tasks
print(result), and executed it. But i am getting these errors - http://dpaste.com/06PTEBG

Comment: @Jeeva As you can see in the traceback, the error is occurring in your code (`Probabilistic_database\src\first_mr.py`). If you need help with it, please ask a new question

Comment: Ok. But i tried to execute my code without this multiprocessing step, it is working fine and i am getting the dictionary as output. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61424/discussion-between-jeeva-and-goncalopp).

Comment: @maybe `result` is some kind of global variable that relies on previous executions to be set? it's hard to tell without reading the code

Comment: I didnt mention the main function and called the process directly, my badness.. :( I changed them and it worked now.. Thanks.. :)

Comment: For python 3 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53938444/3342058